# Pre-pop second dropdown with matched array values from first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `selects` which the first one is pre-populated from my `datatable` column values on button click from the row.

I need to now pre-pop the second `select` with the available values that match the selected first option but struggling.

**All JQuery code**

```
// Table row 'Modify' button click from 'Existing Content' table
$('#selectedDialPlanDataTable').on('click', 'button[name="modifyContentButton"]', function () {  
    // Populates 'Option' dropdown
    let selectedData = selectedDialPlanDataTable.data();

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedData.length; i++) {
        var selectedDataOption = selectedData[i].option;

        if (selectedDataOption == 'start') {
            selectedDataOption = 's';
        }
        //console.log(selectedData)
        $('#modDelOptDropDown').append('<option value="' + selectedDataOption + '">' + selectedData[i].option + '</option>');
    }

    // Removes duplicates from 'Option' dropdown
    var selectedOption = {};
    $('#modDelOptDropDown > option').each(function () {
        if (selectedOption[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            selectedOption[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });
})

// Load 'Existing Dial Plan Content' datatable
function selectedDialPlanButtonClick() {
    selectedDialPlanDataTable = $('#selectedDialPlanDataTable')
        .DataTable({
            "ordering": false,
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            'ajax': {
                "type": 'GET',
                "url": '../_IncomingCallCode/jsons/existingDataPlanData.json',
                "data": function (data) {
                    return data;
                },
                "error": function () {
                    $('#selectedDialPlanDataTable_wrapper').hide();
                    $('#existingRuleLoadErrorMessage').html(
                        '<p>There was an issue retrieving the existing content for <b>' + telNumberSelected + '</b>. Please try again.</p>'
                        + '<p>If the error keeps occurring, please get in touch.</p>').addClass('text-danger');
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "option" },
                { "data": "priority" },
                { "data": "dialPlanFeature" },
                { "data": "appdata" }
            ],
            "destroy": true
        });
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Pencil button clicked**
[image]

**Expanded pre-pop 'Select' Select from code provide**

[image]

Basically i need if the 'Edit' button was clicked for '2' then the priority `select` should pre-pop with `option`s 1-5

I have this working `onchange` with the following code just struggling with when the initial `button` is clicked

**Change code**

```
// Pre-pop's 'Prioriy when 'Modify' button is clicked then the 'Option' dropdown changed
$('#modDelOptDropDown').on('change', function () {
    $('#priorityDropdown').children('option').remove();

    let tableData = selectedDialPlanDataTable.data().toArray();
    //console.log(tableData)
    tableData = tableData.filter(({ option, priority }) => (priority == $('#priorityDropdown').val() || !$('#priorityDropdown').val() || !$(this).val()) &&
        (option == $('#modDelOptDropDown').val() || !$('#modDelOptDropDown').val() || !$(this).val()));

    //console.log(tableData)

    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        //console.log(tableData[i].priority)
        $('#priorityDropdown').append('<option value="' + tableData[i].priority + '">' + tableData[i].priority + '</option>');
    }
});
```

**Array details**

[image]

Comment: You could add `data-option="X"` to your edit buttons, where X is the option value of the row, and then in your click listener, copy the logic of your dropdown listener but retrieve the option value with `$(this).data("option")` instead of `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment this is what I was thinking about: (assuming you can change your HTML to add the `data-option="X"` to your `[name="modifyContentButton"]` buttons)

```
// Table row 'Modify' button click from 'Existing Content' table
$('#selectedDialPlanDataTable').on('click', 'button[name="modifyContentButton"]', function () {  

    let clicked_opt = $(this).data("option");
    if(clicked_opt == 'start') clicked_opt = 's';

    // Populates 'Option' dropdown
    let selectedData = selectedDialPlanDataTable.data();

    var selectedOption = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedData.length; i++) {
        var selectedDataOption = selectedData[i].option;

        if (selectedDataOption == 'start') {
            selectedDataOption = 's';
        }

        if(!selectedOption[selectedDataOption]){
            selectedOption[selectedDataOption] = true;
            //console.log(selectedData)
            $('#modDelOptDropDown').append('<option value="' + selectedDataOption + '"' +(selectedDataOption == clicked_opt ? ' selected' : '')+ '>' + selectedData[i].option + '</option>');
        }
    }

    // Populates 'Priority' dropdown
    let tableData = selectedData.toArray();
    //console.log(tableData)
    tableData = tableData.filter(({ option}) => (option == clicked_opt));

    //console.log(tableData)

    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        //console.log(tableData[i].priority)
            $('#priorityDropdown').append('<option value="' + tableData[i].priority + '">' + tableData[i].priority + '</option>');
    }

})
```

I also combined in a single loop the population and duplicate check for your Option dropdown.

I also added `+(selectedDataOption == clicked_opt ? ' selected' : '')+` in `$('#modDelOptDropDown').append` to preselect the option of the row.

And finally, changed `tableData.filter` to only grab the the data with corresponding option.

**Edit:** defined `clicked_opt` variable and added check & replace for the `start` option

**Edit2:** fixed a mistake on my part (I was using `this.value` in `selectedOption[]`)

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't seem to work. It lists duplicates in the first `select` as its missing the code to remove them but even when i re-add it, the `second `select` does not populate

Comment: It does have code to prevent duplicates, but I made a mistake in it :) However I'm not certain the issues with the 2nd select will be fixed too, since I can't really run the code

Comment: Its not displaying the values in the 2nd `select` when i click the 'Edit' button which is what i'm  stuck on all day

Comment: I would suggest checking the debugger to make sure the `tableData` filter is working properly